# dt.floor count for every 12 hours in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to count the `datetime` occurrences every 12 hours as follows using `dt.floor`.
Here I created a data frame contains 2 days with 1-hour intervals. I have two questions regarding the output.

1. I am expecting the summary would be for every 12 hours i.e, first-row in the output1 should be 12:00 and second row would be 24:00. Instead, I get 00:00 and 12:00. Why is this?
2. Is it possible to create a summary using a specific time? for example, count every 6 Am and 6 PM?

code and input

```
input1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('1/1/2018 00:00:00', periods=48, freq='H'))
input1.columns = ["datetime"]
input1.groupby(input1['datetime'].dt.floor('12H')).count()
```

output-1

```
    datetime
datetime    
2018-01-01 00:00:00 12
2018-01-01 12:00:00 12
2018-01-02 00:00:00 12
2018-01-02 12:00:00 12
```

output-2

```
    datetime
datetime    
2018-01-01 06:00:00 6
2018-01-01 18:00:00 12
2018-01-02 06:00:00 12
2018-01-02 18:00:00 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 24th hour. The time part of a datetime in pandas exists in the range `[00:00:00, 24:00:00)`, which ensures that there's only ever a single representation of the same exact time. (Notice the closure).

```
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime('2012-01-01 24:00:00')
#ParserError: hour must be in 0..23: 2012-01-01 24:00:00
```

For the second point as of `pd.__version__ == '1.1.0'` you can specify the `offset` parameter when you resample. You can also specify which side should be used for the labels. For older versions you will need to use the `base` argument.

```
# pandas < 1.1.0
#input1.resample('12H', on='datetime', base=6).count()

input1.resample('12H', on='datetime', offset='6H').count()
#                     datetime
#datetime                     
#2017-12-31 18:00:00         6
#2018-01-01 06:00:00        12
#2018-01-01 18:00:00        12
#2018-01-02 06:00:00        12
#2018-01-02 18:00:00         6

# Change labels
input1.resample('12H', on='datetime', offset='6H', label='right').count()
#                     datetime
#datetime                     
#2018-01-01 06:00:00         6
#2018-01-01 18:00:00        12
#2018-01-02 06:00:00        12
#2018-01-02 18:00:00        12
#2018-01-03 06:00:00         6
```

Comment: That's a great and simple explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your input data slightly, in order to use `resample`:

```
import pandas as pd

input1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('1/1/2018 00:00:00', periods=48, freq='H'))
input1.columns = ["datetime"]

# add a dummy column
input1['x'] = 'x'

# convert datetime to index...
input1 = input1.set_index('datetime')

# ...so we can use resample, and loffset lets us start at 6 am
t = input1.resample('12h', loffset=pd.Timedelta(hours=6)).count()

# show results
print(t.head())

                      x
datetime               
2018-01-01 06:00:00  12
2018-01-01 18:00:00  12
2018-01-02 06:00:00  12
2018-01-02 18:00:00  12
```